# Sorting scanned documents

Tags: windows, automation, ocr, scanning

Hello there Softwarerecs,

is there a bit of software out there, that is capable of sorting scanned documents that have a marker on the page?

What I need is something that can auto sort, based on what is on the page of the document.

We are going to a trade show, and will give order forms to our customers. The form are split up by material, and it would be good if some software was able to sort the pages into folders with names based on the materials.

It doesn't need to read the whole document for the text contents, just be able to sort if possible.

Regards

Devon